# Resistor switch

Tags: resistors, switches

I'm exploring the idea of creating a resistor switch. The specific switch I plan to use is a 2-terminal pin (no common/GND pin) DIP switch  [SPST](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery/ideas-and-advice/dip-switches-guide) as I'm unable to source an SPDT DIP switch.

Is there any resistor series/parallel hack method to achieve the desired value? I've been scratching my head for a week but haven't figured out how it can be done.

My goal is to construct a switch that allows me to choose between a 33-ohm and a 249-ohm resistor.

Unfortunately, I can't opt for a different switch due to space constraints on the PCB. Still, I'm open to using multiple resistors to achieve values closest to 33-ohm and 249-ohm.

Comment: 33 ohm in series with 216 ohm ... switch in parallel with the 216 ohm resistor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use this schematic:

[image: schematic]

R1 has to be 249 Ω so that it reads as 249 Ω with the switch open. We need to calculate R2, however, which you can do as follows:

$$R1 || R2 = 33\ Ω$$
$$249\ Ω || R2 = 33\ Ω$$
$$\frac{1}{249\ Ω}+\frac{1}{R2}=\frac{1}{33\ Ω}$$
$$\frac{1}{R2}=\frac{1}{33\ Ω}-\frac{1}{249\ Ω}$$
$$\frac{1}{R2}=30.303\ \mathrm{mS} - 4.016\ \mathrm{mS}$$
$$\frac{1}{R2}=26.287\ \mathrm{mS}$$
$$R2=38.042\ Ω$$

The closest standard value to this is 37.9 Ω, though if you want an E96 value you'll need to go with 38.3 Ω. Either of these will get you pretty close to your desired 33 Ω.

---

Note that there is no simple way to do this if you want it to be 33 Ω with the switch open, and 249 Ω with the switch closed. This method requires that the switch-open state be the one with the higher resistance.

I am also assuming that your switch has negligible on-state resistance. If it's a high-resistance switch (like a very low current photorelay, for instance) you can compensate by subtracting the switch's on resistance from the value for R2. I mention this only because at such low resistances, it's possible for even 1 Ω (not *that* much for a very small MOSFET-based switch) to be significant. If, on the other hand, we were talking about 249 kΩ and 33 kΩ, then your switch would need a kΩ of on resistance to have the same effect--which I would call a faulty switch. (I know you, the one asking the question, are using a mechanical switch, but this is important for anyone else who might have the same issue but need to use a MOSFET!)

Comment: Dang beat me to it :)

Comment: Hi, Hearth. To avoid the "schematics for the deaf" appearance I put my little trademark \$t\$ in the bottom right so that the image scales about right in the 640 pixel column width. You could use a grey dot if you wished to be more discreet. The other option is to modify the image link and add 'l', 'm' or 's' before the '.png' to force large, medium or small. You just have to remember to remove it if you ever need to edit the schematic via the link.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the tip. I used the "m" modification, and added a comment in the source so that anyone editing who doesn't see this comment exchange will hopefully see that.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I'll probably go with a 38.3k or 39k + 1.8k. I totally forgot about the switch resistance; it's 0.87 ohms. And no, it's not critical to have 33 ohms on the switch open; 249 ohms also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 249Ω resistor and a 1/(1/33-1/249) Ω resistor switched in parallel with it , which works out to 38.3Ω (a standard value), giving you nominal 249Ω and 33.2Ω.

If you want to get a bit closer to 33.0 *nominal* you could parallel with 38.3 with another resistor, which I'll let you calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll probably go with a 39 ohm, so I can pair it with 1.8k.